# Angular2 Observable List

Tags: angular, observable

I'm running into some issues in my Ionic application (data updated asynchronously but UI not updating accordingly). I've scratched my head over this issue for long and now am trying to test a different approach: using `Observables`. But I'm unsure how to implement it. Tutorials with `Observables` on the net focus on using `Http` service which already returns an `Observable`. My scenario is as follows:

I have a `DataService` containing a list of `Person` objects. The service has a getter that returns this list.

```
export class DataService {
  private _list: Person[] = [];
  get list(): Person[] { return this._list }
}
```

Earlier on, I was directly using this list in my components:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let person of dataService.list">
    {{person.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Now I want to add another getter to `DataService` that would return an `Observable` of the `Person[]` list instead. What I don't know is:

1. How and where to define a `Observable` for the list. Do I define an `Observable` as a `DataService` property and initialise it in the constructor or do I return a new `Observable` directly from the service getter? And how do I wrap the list in an `Observable`?
2. How to use this `Observable` getter in my component? *ngFor="???"
3. When the list is changed asynchronously, how do I signal to the `Observable` that the list has been modified?

I'm hoping this will solve my UI-not-updating issues.

Comment: What kind of object is `Observable`?  Is it RxJava **Observable**?

Comment: RxJs I believe.. That is the library being used by Angular2 by default, right?

Comment: Wow, how little I know of Angular.  It is cross platform for both - Android and iOS?

Comment: And WindowsPhone as well.. =P

Answer (score 16):

Figured it out =)

**DataService**

```
export class DataService {

    private _list: Person[] = [];
    private _observableList: BehaviorSubject<Person[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    get observableList(): Observable<Person[]> { return this._observableList.asObservable() }

    add(person: Person) {
        this._list.push(person);
        this._observableList.next(this._list);
    }

}
```

**Component Template**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let person of dataService.observableList | async">
        {{person.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Got help from here:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-angular-2-apps-using-observable-data-1
https://github.com/jhades/angular2-rxjs-observable-data-services
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

Comment: Don't you need any error-handling callback for Observable?  And what about unsubscribing?

Comment: for my particular case.. i dont think there needs to be any error handling.. its not like the data was coming from an external server where some error could occur.. its just an observable list that is populated by the application itself.. as for unsubscribing, that im unsure of right now.. i believe Angular should take care of unsubscribing when the page is destroyed as im using Angular's `async` pipe.. but not really sure..